# elementary OS freezes when trying to reboot / shutdown?

Tags: release-freya

[image]

Whenever I try to reboot, elementary OS just freezes and my screen stays like this; I tried both `sudo shutdown -r now` and clicking the menu button, but it keeps resulting in a freeze. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. My system was freezing at shutdown and boot.

what i did to solve issue-

edited /etc/default/grub

Changed

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

Updated grub afterward with sudo update-grub at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Turning Off `USB 3.0 legacy mode` or `usb3.0 configuration in pre-os` in BIOS should work.