# Freya cannot shutdown. init: wait for state plymouth shutdownlightdm killed by TERM signal

Tags: release-freya, grub, shutdown, plymouth

I have installed elementary OS freya and I am experiencing shutdown problem.
I cannot shutdown or restart my computer, to do so I have to press power button.I tried:

> ```
> shutdown -h now
> shutdown -P now
> shutdown from the UI
> ```

When I shutdown it shows

**[2969.600864] init: wait-for-state (plymouth-shutdownlightdm) main process (14172) killed by TERM signal**

I also tried to change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`
and changed `CONCURRENCY` to `none` in `/etc/init.d/rc`.
Still no luck

Do I have to press power button everytime or is there any solution for this? Secondly, is doing so safe?

Comment: please [edit] your post and add the error message you got, when you executed the commands in terminal. (Please add total message--use copy&paste--no screenshots)

Comment: okay, did that. Hope that helps

Comment: which command you used?

Comment: Bizarre--without `sudo` you got that error. You have to use `sudo` befor other wise you will get `shutdown: Need to be root` message

Comment: No, I tried doing shutdown both by using 
 sudo shutdown -h now # as normal user
and also by sudo su
shutdown -h now # as root

Comment: fine, I posted commands in answer, let me which one worked for you

Comment: Non off the tips that have bin shared are working. What else could I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed elementary OS freya and I am experiencing the same shutdown problem. In my case I installed AMD Radeon driver (graphic card) to my hardware in Lenovo G50-80 laptop. Packages are in the repository:

```
# sudo apt-get install fglrx-core fglrxamdcccle
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it was the graphic driver that was causing the problem. I wonder when will the computer manufacturing companies start making drivers for all the machines they ship.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo shutdown -h <time in minute>`

### Example `sudo shutdown -h 0`

Try `sudo shutdown -r <time in minute>` for reboot in time.
Reboot can also use `sudo reboot`

---

Solution 1:
Edit /etc/default/grub file

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"  
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=pci"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`

Source -- [Link](http://michalorman.com/2013/10/fix-ubuntu-freeze-during-restart/)

---

Solution 2:
Edit /etc/default/grub file

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"  
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Already did that. Still the same.

Comment: I did some googling and found this bug in bugzilla. It says resolved patch already available. I want to get that patch. Where can I get it?

[bugzilla link](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106001)
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106001

Comment: try [this](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/elementary-os-freezes-when-trying-to-reboot-shutdown)

Comment: or you can try [this](http://michalorman.com/2013/10/fix-ubuntu-freeze-during-restart/).
Remember after all command `sudo update-grub`

Comment: tried that but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

By Using terminal you can simply run following commands to shutdown and restart.

For Shutdown

```
sudo init 0
```

For Restart

```
sudo init 6
```

You will be asked to enter password, after entering password you are cool.

Answer (score -1):

This is very radical and application will **not** be closed properly. However, if you quit everything correctly that shouldn't be an issue.

```
sudo poweroff
```

will kill the power instantly, without waiting for plymouth. **This is not recommended**, but until this issue (which affects me too) is fixed, it should work fine.

My System:

```
System:    Host: FuckTheSystem Kernel: 4.4.6-040406-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 5.2.1) 
           Desktop: Gnome Distro: elementary OS 0.3.2 freya
Machine:   System: ECT product: N/A
           Mobo: Notebook model: W65_67SF Bios: American Megatrends version: 1.03.03 date: 04/01/2014
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-4810MQ CPU (-HT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 22349.8 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 2794.093 MHz 2: 2800.00 MHz 3: 2805.468 MHz 4: 2789.937 MHz 5: 2782.500 MHz 6: 2825.265 MHz 7: 2780.859 MHz 8: 2764.453 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           X.Org: 1.17.1 driver: intel Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.9 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 
           Card-2: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0 
           Card-3: Logitech driver: USB Audio usb-ID: 003-006 
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k4.4.6-040406-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
           driver: r8169 ver: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 04:00.2
           IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 80:fa:5b:06:6f:e4
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 3160 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlan0 state: up mac: 30:3a:64:54:c7:7f
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 370.1GB (3.8% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 120.0GB temp: 0C 
           2: id: /dev/sdb model: Samsung_SSD_840 size: 250.1GB temp: 0C 
Partition: ID: / size: 213G used: 14G (7%) fs: ext4 
RAID:      No RAID devices detected - /proc/mdstat and md_mod kernel raid module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 14.0C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A 
Info:      Processes: 275 Uptime: 59 min Memory: 1072.9/15931.8MB Runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.9.3 
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.11) inxi: 1.9.17
```