# How to take screenshots at shutdown?

Tags: release-freya, shutdown, screenshot

I have a shutdown problem similar to this one: [Freya cannot shutdown. init: wait for state plymouth shutdownlightdm killed by TERM signal](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/freya-cannot-shutdown-init-wait-for-state-plymouth-shutdownlightdm-killed-by-t)

However, there is plenty of output before the final line when the shutdown process stops that I can see for a split second only (there also seems to be a compatibility/driver issue with the AMD graphics card).

It's impossible to write down the output, so I'd like to take screenshots during the shutdown process before posting my question here. Is that possible and if yes, how? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the answers in your linked question? [This](http://michalorman.com/2013/10/fix-ubuntu-freeze-during-restart/) seems like it may fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried the link you posted, it didn't work though (although my machine is also a Dell Laptop).

Comment: Try http://superuser.com/a/290450/544148 which include some information about taking a BIOS screenshot (same thing)

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to take an actual screenshot, although if the error occurs early enough in the shutdown process (before the logger service is stopped and the hdd's have been unmounted) it should be visible in your logs via `less /var/log/syslog`. If you can't see anything obvious, [these answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53252/how-to-read-the-messages-during-power-off) show various ways to enable more thorough logging.

Alternately I suppose it is probably easier to just use a camera. ;p

Comment: Thanks for the hint with syslog, it doesn't show though. I'll go for the camera then :)